# Image Banner Size - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to have a UIImageView banner that fills the entire width of the screen on all iPhone devices. If I want to the aspect ratio to be 2.5:1, then should I make the width of the image 320 x 3 = 960 and the height 960 / 2.5 = 384?

Or do I need to make the image twice or three times the size of the largest possible banner (the width of the 6 Plus)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build an @2x version for iPhone 5 a slightly wider @2x version for the iPhone 6, and a wider still @3x version for the 6 plus. You should write your code to install the different sized images on each device. (You could use size classes in IB to tell the 6 plus apart from the 5 and 6)

Comment: would you mind elaborating a bit more? I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by installing different sized images on each device. Don't they all get packaged and downloaded when the user installs my app initially? And is there a way to do this without size classes?

Comment: Take a look at asset catalogs. You create a logical image, and then you install art at 1x, 2x, and 3x resolutions into the catalog. Normally they are all included for all devices, but with the advent of app thinning, the app store is smart enough to build a version for each target device that only uses the assets at it's screen resolution (@2x for most devices, @3x for the 6 plus, and non-retina for the iPad 2 and original iPad mini, the only remaining non-retina devices.)

Comment: And yes, support for images `@1x`, `@2x`, and `@3x` resolutions is independent of size classes. Size classes are used to handle different device sizes, which is different than device screen resolution.